# Syslog4J (syslog) server not starting on Mac

Tags: java, syslog, syslog4j

I have the following code for custom syslog server (using Syslog4J) which works on Windows.

```
        final UDPNetSyslogServerConfig udpConfig = new UDPNetSyslogServerConfig();
        udpConfig.setPort(Integer.parseInt(port));
        udpConfig.setHost(host);
        udpConfig.addEventHandler(new Handler());
        udpConfig.setUseDaemonThread(false);

        SyslogServerIF server = SyslogServer.createInstance(host + port, udpConfig);
        server.run();
```

It listens for the incoming events and invokes handler (method) whenever the event is received.

If I run the same code on Mac, it just comes out. Even if I use a loop to wait for the events, the events are not captured.

```
        while (!stop) {
            SyslogUtility.sleep(1000);
        }
```

Even the handler's initialize() method is not invoked on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

What port are you trying to use on Mac?

Is it in conflict with an in-use port (default is 514)?

Check `/etc/syslog.conf` on MacOS to see what port it is using for the built in syslog. On Ubuntu, this can be found in `/etc/rsyslog.conf`.